# Get all keys of a document having max keyvalue and grouped on another field

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have my documents like this in mongo

```
{ "MappedTitle" : ObjectId("59e44696a4585255569f19d8"), "Title" : "Accounting Clerk", "MedianSalary" : 31200, "TimeToFill" : "Short" }
{ "MappedTitle" : ObjectId("59e44698a4585255569f19db"), "Title" : "Accounting Clerk", "MedianSalary" : 35360, "TimeToFill" : "Short" }
{ "MappedTitle" : ObjectId("59e44694a4585255569f19d7"), "Title" : "Controller (general)", "MedianSalary" : 63001, "TimeToFill" : "Medium" }
{ "MappedTitle" : ObjectId("59e44697a4585255569f19d9"), "Title" : "Controller (general)", "MedianSalary" : 75000, "TimeToFill" : "Medium" }
{ "MappedTitle" : ObjectId("59e44697a4585255569f19da"), "Title" : "Controller (general)", "MedianSalary" : 65000, "TimeToFill" : "Medium" }
{ "MappedTitle" : ObjectId("59e44694a4585255569f19d7"), "Title" : "Financial Reporting Manager", "MedianSalary" : 63001, "TimeToFill" : "Medium" }
{ "MappedTitle" : ObjectId("59e44697a4585255569f19d9"), "Title" : "Financial Reporting Manager", "MedianSalary" : 75000, "TimeToFill" : "Medium" }
{ "MappedTitle" : ObjectId("59e44697a4585255569f19da"), "Title" : "Financial Reporting Manager", "MedianSalary" : 65000, "TimeToFill" : "Medium" }
{ "MappedTitle" : ObjectId("59e446a3a4585255569f19e2"), "Title" : "Healthcare Administrator", "MedianSalary" : 58132, "TimeToFill" : "Medium" }
{ "MappedTitle" : ObjectId("59e446a5a4585255569f19e3"), "Title" : "Healthcare Administrator", "MedianSalary" : 38000, "TimeToFill" : "Short" }
```

I want to fetch the document with max `MedianSalary` grouped on `Title` field. I come up with this query -

```
# titles is a list of titles for which I want to get the documents

db.MyCollection.aggregate({$match: {Title: {$in: titles}}}, {$group: {_id: "$Title", "maxValue": {$max: "$MedianSalary"}}}).pretty()
{ "_id" : "Financial Reporting Manager", "maxValue" : 75000 }
{ "_id" : "Controller (general)", "maxValue" : 75000 }
{ "_id" : "Healthcare Administrator", "maxValue" : 58132 }
{ "_id" : "Accounting Clerk", "maxValue" : 35360 }
```

Its giving the correct result but I want other fields -`TimeToFill` and `MappedTitle` of the matched document as well

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following snippet:

```
db.MyCollection.aggregate(
   {
      $match: {Title: {$in: titles}}
   }, 
   { 
      $group: {
         _id: "$Title", 
         "maxValue": {$max: "$MedianSalary"},
         "TimeToFill": {$first: "$TimeToFill"},
         "MappedTitle": {$first: "$MappedTitle"}
      }
   }).pretty()
```

You can use `$first` in order to get the rest of omitted fields while using `$group`. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Hello @oneturkmen, I just tested this for query, maxValue is coming out to be correct but TimeToFill & MappedTitle are coming from the 1st document from each group and not from the matched document.  Example - For Financial Reporting Manager, maxValue is coming as 75000(correct), but MappedTitle is coming as  59e44694a4585255569f19d7, it should really come as 59e44697a4585255569f19d9 (see document snippet above)

Comment: I got the answer, we should use $sort before $group to get the desired result. Just added the following line - {$sort: {MedianSalary: -1}} before - {$group: {........}}